# My Plugin is not searched in maven central repository even though I have added in buildscript's repositories

Tags: gradle

My Plugin is not searched in maven central repository when i start running my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" 
        }
    }
}
plugins {
     id 'net.sf.jbddi.jbddi-core' version '1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

I am getting the below error.

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'net.sf.jbddi.jbddi-core', version: '1.0.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.sf.jbddi.jbddi-core:net.sf.jbddi.jbddi-core.gradle.plugin:1.0.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Answer (score 0):

the `buildscript` `dependencies` are for Gradle plugins only;

just define the repository outside of that block:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have already defined mavenCentral() in repositories block outside of the buildscript .
    
    repositories {
 mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }